# Acumatica data from one custom field to another

Tags: acumatica

I added two custom fields.One on sales order discount detail tab and one on invoices discount detail tab.And when I prepare the invoice from sales order screen,I want the data in my custom field on the sales order form to automatically insert into the custom field on invoices screen.I am still new to acumatica customization.So please give me some idea on this matter.

Answer (score 2):

**To the "being new" and "some idea on this matter" portion:**

Being new to Acumatica, I'd suggest you start with the [training material](https://openuni.acumatica.com/learning-paths/developer-learning-paths/development/) they provide.  In this case, focus on T220 as it explains how to do what you are asking.  To appease the moderators on Stack Overflow, you should try to include more detail in your questions.  Code samples are encouraged, as well as screen shots when applicable.

The Sales Order screen is SO301000 using the graph SOOrderEntry.  The Invoice screen is SO303000 using the graph SOInvoiceEntry. This is important to know because while the action for PrepareInvoice is in SOOrderEntry, it will call InvoiceOrder in SOOrderEntry which then initializes the graph SOInvoiceEntry (the invoice screen) and calls SOInvoiceEntry's InvoiceOrder method.

From SOOrderEntry.CreateInvoice:

```
SOInvoiceEntry ie = PXGraph.CreateInstance<SOInvoiceEntry>();
...
ie.InvoiceOrder((DateTime)ie.Accessinfo.BusinessDate, res, details,
   customer.Current, created, quickProcessFlow, !isMassProcess);
```

You want to be mindful of where the fields you update are truly managed.  What I mean by that is that business logic requires event handlers to fire when certain fields change.  These event handlers interact with each other in that one event handler may cause a change that triggers another event handler.  If the events are not occuring in the same graph as where you update the field, then you risk the important business logic not firing and cause data integrity issues.

In short, you are calling PrepareInvoice from SOOrderEntry, but you want to manipulate a field on the Invoice.  Therefore, it is most appropriate to put your business logic for those invoice fields into SOInvoiceEntry. Of course, the custom fields on the SO would be maintained in SOOrderEntry.  The real trick is going to come in getting your fields updated in SOInvoiceEntry from the method being used in SOOrderEntry.

If you need business logic on your custom invoice field(s), do that in SOInvoiceEntry because that is where the invoice is created once you dig into the code.  To set the values, you can still put your code in SOOrderEntry, but prefix it with the name of the graph instance for SOInvoiceEntry.  In standard code, Acumatica called that graph instance ie.  Therefore, you would use syntax like ie.Document.Current to refer to the current record of the document view in SOInvoiceEntry.

If you follow all that, it's time to muddy the waters a little more.  SOInvoiceEntry actually inherits from ARInvoiceEntry.  That means that when placing code for the invoice, you need to decide if it applies to all AR Invoices or only the ones coming from the SO's PrepareInvoice method.  If you need your changes to apply to all invoices, you need to put your business logic of the AR invoice into ARInvoiceEntry.

**To the coding part of the question:**

You did not specify where the fields are that you want to copy from or to.  I will assume on the SOLine and ARTran (invoice line).  In this case, a lot more digging takes down into CreateTranFromShipLine in SOInvoiceEntry.  That methed creates the invoice line and returns it (as ARTran).  If we override THAT method, we can find our DAC extension on the ARTran record and on the SOLine record and copy the value in the override.

```
using PX.Data;
using PX.Objects.AR;

namespace PX.Objects.SO
{
    public class SOInvoiceEntry_Extension : PXGraphExtension<SOInvoiceEntry>
    {
        public static bool IsActive()
        {
            // Insert your logic for returning whether or not this shoudl be active
            return true;
        }

        public delegate ARTran CreateTranFromShipLineDelegate(ARInvoice newdoc, SOOrderType ordertype, string operation, SOLine orderline, ref SOShipLine shipline);
        [PXOverride]
        public virtual ARTran CreateTranFromShipLine(ARInvoice newdoc, SOOrderType ordertype, string operation, SOLine orderline, ref SOShipLine shipline, CreateTranFromShipLineDelegate del)
        {
            ARTran tran = del.Invoke(newdoc, ordertype, operation, orderline, ref shipline);

            ARTranExt arTranExt = tran.GetExtension<ARTranExt>();
            SOLineExt soLineExt = orderline.GetExtension<SOLineExt>();

            Base.Caches[typeof(ARTran)].SetValueExt<ARTranExt.usrMyCustomField>(arTranExt, soLineExt.UsrMyCustomField);

            return tran;
        }
    }
}
```

ARTran is a DAC, but it references the cache which is the entire record of the database.  By accessing the custom field as a DAC extension, you should be updating the cacheed record.  The method does not update the view, nor does it appear to save the record, so I don't think (could be wrong) that you need to actually update the cache.  If you do need to update the cache, simply add the following line after the SetValueExt line:

```
Base.Caches[typeof(ARTran)].Update(arTranExt);
```

Comment: Thank you for the solution brian.The Custom fields that I want to copy and paste are from SOOrderDiscountDetail to ARInvoiceDiscountDetail